# Bootstrap Table loading external data - No matching records found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to get the plugin Bootstrap Table to work with the example code provided on the official site (http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/). For some reason it doesn't seem to work, all I get is "No matching records found".
Here's my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1r3s3qjn/ which is based on the official example http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/14/light/, which works.

The data I'm trying to load is also from the official site: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json

Code snippet:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Id</th>
            <th data-field="name">Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Can anyone get this simple example to work?

EDIT:

I just managed to get this to work locally (with both the code and the data saved locally). However, this only seems to work in Firefox (37.0.2). Both Chrome (42.0.23) and IE11 still display the "No matching records found".

Comment: you have a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in your js if you use this code in you server wenzhixin.net you should have no problem with this error

Comment: read more here :http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/4613398

Comment: I am trying to do this in `Table from data` using the `ajax` it's working. @madalinivascu is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing an error related to **Cross origin/Access-Control-Allow-Origin** issue.
provide data from same domain.

or try like http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#basic-table-from-data. Read data using CORS and call bootstrapTable function.